# Multistaging capistrano: db:migrate working correctly on production but not on staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I have set up capistrano to deploy to staging and production. Honestly, I'm not very familiar with capistrano. I did this via just using standard capistrano (not multi-host). I pass a variable in such as:

```
cap production deploy
cap staging deploy
```

But my `db:migrate` isn't working correcty.

with cat staging deploy:
I get shis:

```
  * executing "cd /data/sites/staging.domain.com/apps/d-rails/releases/20121212203353 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
```

and would like (just sub production -> staging):

```
* executing "cd /data/sites/staging.domain.com/apps/d-rails/releases/20121212203353 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=staging  db:migrate"
```

How would I set this up? Or what should I look at first to fix?

In my deploy.rb, I have:

```
task :production do
  set :deploy_to, "/data/sites/domain.com/apps/#{application}"
end

task :staging do
  set :deploy_to, "/data/sites/staging.domain.com/apps/#{application}"
  after 'deploy:update_code' do
    run "cd #{release_path}; RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace"
  end
end
```

thx in advance

Comment: do you use the multistaging feature of capistrano? and why are staging and production are deployed to the same folder?

Comment: not using multistaging feature; not sure about your deploy ?, one goes to domain.com, the other to staging.domain.com

Comment: I've written you an answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be easier to use capistrano's multistaging feature. Here is my setup for production and staging deployment:

**config/deploy.rb**

```
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'
require 'bundler/capistrano'

set :application, "yourappname"
set :repository,  "git@yourhost.com:yourrepo.git"
set :stages, %w(production staging)
set :default_stage, "staging" # running "cap deploy" deploys to staging, "cap production deploy" deploys to production
set :user, "deploy" # the ssh user which does the deployment on the server
set :use_sudo, false
set :scm, :git

set :default_environment, {
  'PATH' => "/usr/local/rbenv/shims:/usr/local/rbenv/bin:/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin:$PATH"
}
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:migrate"

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

The `set :default_environment` is needed if you have to include some additional pathes for your deployment (because, the normal `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` isn't included when capistrano logs into the server)

**config/deploy/production.rb**

```
set :rails_env, "production"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/your_production_folder"

role :web, "example.com"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "example.com"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "example.com", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
```

**config/deploy/staging.rb**

```
set :rails_env, "staging"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/your_staging_folder"

role :web, "example.com"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "example.com"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "example.com", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
```

Be sure to include the RailsEnv variable in your VirtualHost config. If you are using Apache, this would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName staging.example.com
  ServerAlias www.staging.example.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/your_staging_folder/current/public
  <Directory /var/www/your_staging_folder/current/public>
    # This relaxes Apache security settings.
    AllowOverride all
    # MultiViews must be turned off.
    Options -MultiViews
    #AuthName "Staging Server"
    #AuthType Basic
    #AuthUserFile /var/staging.htpasswd
    #require valid-user
  </Directory>
  RailsEnv staging
</VirtualHost>
```

The uncommented `AuthName`, `AuthType` is used if you want to password protect your staging environment. When you are finished configuring this stuff, test your deployment with `cap deploy:setup`, this sets up the folder structure. A `cap deploy:cold` will copy all the files of your application to the directory. A `cap deploy:migrate` migrates your db. But you can also only just do a `cap deploy`.

Another thing is, that you have to set up a staging env in the rails app. For this, copy the `config/environments/production.rb` (or development.rb, what you prefer) to `staging.rb` and adjust the configs for your needs.

I hope I haven't forgotten anything ;) Let me know if you have any further problems